# Does the surcharge apply only if you tap the card in Australia?

Tags: australia, money, payment-cards

Some restaurants in Australia have a surcharge if you use a credit card. I've heard from someone who lives in Australia that this surcharge only applies if you tap the card (paywave or paypass), but if you insert the card into the card reader, then you don't get charged the surcharge.

Is this indeed the case in all businesses in Australia? If so, is there any documented proof of this fact?

Comment: Chip and contactless are processed in essentially the same way on the same networks and I can't imagine any reason for there to be a difference in cost between them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Aussie here.  As far as I'm aware, whoever told you that was flat out wrong: **you're charged for credit card use, regardless of whether you tap, insert or swipe**.

I suspect that your contact is confused by the fact that EFTPOS (direct bank payment) is almost always free and usually done by inserting the card, while credit cards more often have surcharges and are usually tapped (PayWave is ubiquitous in Australia).